# Selenium Java - Page Object Model Query

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, pageobjects

Imagine there is a page say http://google.com/AddUser and here you enter details for a record and click save. Once you do this the page redirects to

**http://google.com/userList**

where you can see list of users including the new record you just entered.

If we are going by page object model, the method to enter details and save record should exist on `AddUser.java` and the method to validate if the record was actually saved and displayed should be on `UserList.java`

If we consider addUser and userList are the corresponding objects for both classes it will be something like below :

```
addUser.enterDetailsSaveRecord();

userList.validateSavedRecord();
```

So in my Test case i would need to call 2 separate methods, one for the action and other to validate.

Both `AddUser.java` and `UserList.java` have  `BasePage.java` as the superclass.
Is there a way to club them both into a single method or is there something I'm going about in a wrong way and is there a better approach?

Thank you

Comment: what is the problem with the current approach. what you described is your implementation, which I find nothing wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `PageFactory` you are having 2 PageObjects as `AddUser.java` and `UserList.java`. So assuming you are passing the appropriate arguments while invoking the methods, the following works for you:

```
addUser.enterDetailsSaveRecord();
userList.validateSavedRecord();
```

But a word from Best Practices, `Assertions should be done in a seperate utility/package/class` which is in similar line with @JeffC comment:

> `Best practice is to keep the validation code out of the page objects`

Hence, you should be creating a seperate common utility/package/class which will handle all the `Assertions`. You can call the `class` containing the `Assertions` from your `PageObject` class as well.

So your entire Test Environment will contain 3 `Packages`. One package containing the  `main()/@Test` class, one package containing the `PageObjects` e.g. `AddUser.java` and one `Utility` package with the class for containing the `Assertions` e.g `validateSavedRecord()`.

Answer (score 1):

I don't see anything wrong with your approach either, although, my approach is usually to logically separate functional interaction with the application from testing functions.  So, I would still have

```
addUser.enterDetailsSaveRecord();
```

but for userList I would use

```
UserItem foundUser = userList.findUser(targetUser);
```

where UserItem is a row in the table of users.  My test would then verify that foundUser was correct.

Although this ends up with a few more lines of code, it results in the object model cleanly and simply modeling the object under test, and the testing code being found in the test itself.

Comment: This is the way I create my page objects also. Best practice is to keep the validation code out of the page objects. The way to get around that is to have the page objects return the data needed and have the script itself do the validation in an `Assert`.

Answer (score -1):

Your approach is correct. These methods should belong to different pages.
Please update method as:

```
public UserList enterDetailsSaveRecord() {
// your code to save the details
return new UserList();
}
```

thus you can use it as:

```
addUser.enterDetailsSaveRecord().validateSavedRecord()
```

Comment: You can't validate the saved record until you are on the UserList page. Your code listed above doesn't demonstrate that clearly.

Comment: As soon as you enterDetails and click save, website will automatically redirect you to new page. Above code just showing the instead of creating a new object in test script, we can create new object in method itself (Factory method) and can used as chaining in the same line

Comment: Yeah but that turns into a mess because if you go crazy with this, you can have `page1.dosomeThingOnPage2().dosomeThingOnPage3().dosomeThingOnPage4().dosomeThingOnPage5();` and you end up with a one liner that is navigating through the entire site. It makes it very hard to follow what is going on.

Comment: Yes, you're right, you will end up with one liner and you will come to know that it is necessary and important step in terms of memory management.

Comment: This definitely makes it less readable, why do you think it has advantages in memory management? While chaining, you still create each page object as you would without chaining.